# JQuery Tabs, putting my divs into display:none

Tags: jquery, shopify

I have implemented some tabs into my site to use for product description.

Its working, but the text on each tab disappears after 2 secs, something after a count is adding the display:none style to the div.

It picks up the first 5 div with info from a source in Shopify then the last div is picked up from another place.

Also the first div gets filled with all the information from each div until you click the tab at the top it just shows the appropriate info.

This is the code:

```
<script>
 $(function() {                                   // <== shorter form of doc ready
$('#tabs > div').hide();
$('#tabs div:first').fadeIn('slow');
$('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
$('#tabs ul li a').click(function(){
    $('#tabs ul li.active').removeClass('active');  // <== Only what you need
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var selectedTab=$(this).attr('href');
    $('#tabs > div').fadeOut('slow', function() {       // <== Use a callback
        $(selectedTab).delay(500).fadeIn('slow');          // <== add a delay
    });        
    return false;
});


});
    </script>



<div id="tabs">
   <ul class="tabs">
     <li><a class="active" href="#tab-1">Why we love it</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-2">Made With</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-3">How to use</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-4">Characteristics</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-5">Meet the brand</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab-6">Recipes</a></li>
   </ul>
  <div class="tabcontainer">
  <div class="description" itemprop="description">
    {{ product.description }}
  <div id="tab-5">
  {% if product.vendor == 'Loving Earth' %}
  {% include 'lovingearth' %}
  {% endif %}   
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the markup for tabs 2,3,4 and 6?

Comment: its inside the product display just like <div id="tab-5">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#tabs > div').fadeOut('slow', function() {       // <== Use a callback
    $(selectedTab).delay(500).fadeIn('slow');          // <== add a delay
});        
return false;
```

to this:

```
 $('.tabcontainer div').fadeOut('slow', function() {       // <== Use a callback
    $(selectedTab).delay(500).fadeIn('slow');          // <== add a delay
});        
return false;
```

Since `$('#tabs > div')` is selecting every element inside `<div id="tabs">` all of them are being hidden—including `tabcontainer`. Since `tabcontainer` is the parent of the `div`s you're trying then `fadeIn()` : `$(selectedTab).delay(500).fadeIn('slow')`, there is no result as it's still sitting inside of its *hidden* parent.

Also, your `<li><a class="selected">...` is set in the markup with the class on the `<a>` but then in the script, you're adding the class to the `<li>` : `$('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active')`. Which is unrelated, but worthing point out.

> **An example [Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/qg4xQnhOmpUFKDdlGDB7?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/qg4xQnhOmpUFKDdlGDB7?p=preview)** with the changes outline above.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the help, that worked for tabcontainer but now display:none is appearing on the next div

  <div class="description" itemprop="description">

Comment: Right, because it's included in that initial selector. If you did something like `$('.tabcontainer div').not('.description').fadeOut(...)` that would exclude the `div` in question.

Comment: Actually, in your example `tab-5` is a child of `<div class="description" itemprop="description">`, so you need to simply modify `$('.tabcontainer div')` to be `$('.tabcontainer .description div')`

Comment: Worked! Awesome thank you very much, sorry to ask one last question - do you know why when it first loads all of the text from each div gets put into tab-1 but then when you cycle through and back to tab-1 its only what should be on there

Comment: Can you post the output of the code? As in, include the markup for the browsers result with all the divs and no server-side code? Without that, it's difficult to debug.

Comment: do you mean the elements? This is the url - http://begoodorganics.com/collections/grains-pulses-pastas/products/buckinis everything goes into the correct divs i cant figure out why it does this at the start

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this line

```
$('#tabs > div').fadeOut('slow', function() {       // this line
    $(selectedTab).delay(500).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

You're causing all the `div` in `#tabs` to `fadeOut`. I assume you want to hide the `#tab-5` when other link is clicked. You probably want to do this.

```
$('#tab-5').fadeOut('slow', function() {       // this line
    $(selectedTab).delay(500).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

A more appropriate solution for your case will be

```
$('div[id^=tabs]').fadeOut('slow', function() {       // this line
    $(selectedTab).delay(500).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This will hide all the div with id starting with `tabs`

Comment: thanks for the help, all the tabs look like #tab-5 (<div id="tab-6">,<div id="tab-4"> etc), but are pulled from a different location. That seems to hide everything. The text i want shows for a small time - and i can see in the inspect element the style display:none show - the display:none shows up on the container div not each individual div.

Comment: Well, if the container containing the individual div is hidden, then all the individual div won't be visible as well. I think the 3rd options in my answer is what you need. Notably the `div[id^=tabs]`.